# Heroku mlab Add-On deleted after migration to mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, add-on

I have a big problem, today I tried migrating my mlab MongoDB sandbox into MongoDB Atlas. I'm using Heroku for my Nightscout instance, this is a cloud based cgm-app for type 1 diabetes patients and it displays my bloodglucose values.

I followed these steps for the migration https://docs.mlab.com/how-to-migrate-to-atlas/#migration-prereqs

I connected my mlab database to my MongoDB project after the Migration the button "connect to mlab" reappeared, it looks like there was no connection established, but I noticed that after I deleted the add-on in heroku, I think that the migration was not correctly done, but I havent got any error message, everything was fine.

I did everything exactly like its written down, now my nightscout site is no longer available and also the database from the deleted mlab MongoDB add-on is lost.

Is there any possibiltie to get my database back. it stored my bg-values over the last 2 years and everything is lost, I haven't made any backup and I'm addicted to that data :(

Comment: Contact mlab and/or atlas support. And not making a backup is  a massive fail.

Answer (score 0):

did you resolve your problem, or was it even one? I migrated today and everything worked fine. Nightscout is working, all old and new values are stored and reportable via Nightscout Reporter.

But in my Mongo Atlas Account I can't access mLab account anymore. It tell's me to disconnect and try reconnect. I'm just not sure if that is an error or just the way it is - as I deleted my only connection to mLab through deleting my MongoDB addon in my Heroku App - I think.

I don't recall ever setting up a real MongoDB account. And the connection during migration was established through opening my own/single MongoDB database (through Heroku Dashboard), which doesn't exist anymore...

I don't think there is any way, to get an already deleted database back. For other people who fear problems like that, you could export your MongoDB database before migration & deletion as binary, json or csv - I tried that to be safe, but couldn't work the commandline properly... I really don't/didn't know what I'm doing there (technical noob) - I'm just glad there are instructions and videos out there and that it worked fine for me.

These are the instructions I should've used (I used different ones when I did it, the following ones are all in all the same, but much clearer & easier):

https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas-nightscout-demo-video/

https://docs.mlab.com/how-to-migrate-nightscout-sandbox-heroku-addons-to-atlas/

https://insulinclub.de/index.php?thread/32513-mongodb-shutdown-heroku-nightscout-was-jetzt/